# Android - getView() in CustomCursorAdapter and ListView?

Tags: android, android-listview, android-adapter

I've read multiple (a lot, actually) of questions here on StackOverflow and on other websites about which methods to override when making a CustomCursorAdapter, but I still don't understand.

Some say that getView() delegates directly to newView() and bindView(), so is therefore unnecessary in a CursorAdapter.  However, it seems that using a getView() method is the only way to incorporate a ViewHolder.

My intention is to put a CheckBox in each row of my ListView, but I'm not sure how to deal with the view recycling.

Could somebody please clarify this for me?  Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Look at googleshelves project. They use a viewholder a newview and bindview. Personally I've always used getview.